# Como resolver o erro java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 25, Size: 25

Tags: java, jsp

Estou desenvolvendo um questionário online em JSP, onde, ao usuário seleciona o radio de cada questão a ser validada. Exemplo: um questionário de 25 questões, se o usuário chegar na 25 e clicar na anterior 24 e da um próximo para a 25, gera o erro `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 25, Size: 25`. Estava pesquisando na Internet e encontrei que este erro pode ocorrer, se um método tenta acessar um endereço de memória em um array que não existe, e ou já chegou em seu limite.

Trecho da classe `Exam.class` que o sistema acusa o erro:

Configuração Funciona, porem, da erro, se o usuário volta na ultima questões do exame e clicar na posterior

```
    for(int i=0;i<taken-1;i++){ 
        System.out.println("i ExamController: "+i+ "taken: "+taken);
        //o erro ocorre aqui!!!!
        if((userSelectionsList.get(i)-1)==correctAnswersList.get(i)){
            totalCorrect++;
            System.out.println("totalCorrect ExamController: "+totalCorrect);
        }
    }
```

Trecho do código que chama o método calcularResultado:
/*O exame será finalizado quando o usuário finalizar ou quando o limite de tempo para o exame é longo.*/

```
        else if("Finish Exam".equals(action)||( minute==0 && second==0))
        {   finish=true;
        /*Submetendo o Exame e Avaliação Resultado Exame. Quando o usuário clica no botão Concluir, ExamController
         *chama o método calculateResult () passando o objeto Exame, calculateResult ()*/
            int result=exam.calculateResult(exam,exam.questionList.size());                 
            request.setAttribute("result",result);              
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsps/result.jsp").forward(request,response);             
        }
```

Erro no console:

> Número pergunta 0 recuperado  Número pergunta 1 recuperado  Número
>   pergunta 2 recuperado  Número pergunta 3 recuperado  Número pergunta 4
>   recuperado  Número pergunta 5 recuperado  Número pergunta 6 recuperado
>   Número pergunta 7 recuperado  Número pergunta 8 recuperado  Número
>   pergunta 9 recuperado  Número pergunta 10 recuperado  Número pergunta
>   11 recuperado  Número pergunta 12 recuperado  Número pergunta 13
>   recuperado  Número pergunta 14 recuperado  Número pergunta 15
>   recuperado  Número pergunta 16 recuperado  Número pergunta 17
>   recuperado  Número pergunta 18 recuperado  Número pergunta 19
>   recuperado  Número pergunta 20 recuperado  Número pergunta 21
>   recuperado  Número pergunta 22 recuperado  Número pergunta 23
>   recuperado  Número pergunta 24 recuperado  Você clicou Botão Anterior
>   Número pergunta 23 recuperado  Número pergunta 24 recuperado  Você
>   clicou Botão Anterior Número pergunta 23 recuperado  Você clicou Botão
>   Anterior Número pergunta 22 recuperado  Número pergunta 23 recuperado 
>   Número pergunta 24 recuperado
>
> i ExamController: 0taken: 32 totalCorrect ExamController: 1 i
>   ExamController: 1taken: 32 i ExamController: 2taken: 32 i
>   ExamController: 3taken: 32 i ExamController: 4taken: 32 i
>   ExamController: 5taken: 32 i ExamController: 6taken: 32 i
>   ExamController: 7taken: 32 i ExamController: 8taken: 32 i
>   ExamController: 9taken: 32 i ExamController: 10taken: 32 i
>   ExamController: 11taken: 32 totalCorrect ExamController: 2 i
>   ExamController: 12taken: 32 totalCorrect ExamController: 3 i
>   ExamController: 13taken: 32 i ExamController: 14taken: 32 i
>   ExamController: 15taken: 32 i ExamController: 16taken: 32 i
>   ExamController: 17taken: 32 i ExamController: 18taken: 32 i
>   ExamController: 19taken: 32 i ExamController: 20taken: 32
>
> jun 17, 2016 5:52:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
>   invoke GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet
>   [br.com.tkcsapcd.quiz.controller.ExamController] in context with path
>   [/Tkcsapcd_cadastros] threw exception
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 25, Size: 25  at
>   java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)   at
>   br.com.tkcsapcd.quizz.Exam.calculateResult(Exam.java:128)     at
>   br.com.tkcsapcd.quiz.controller.ExamController.doPost(ExamController.java:127)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Como eu poderia resolver isso?

Answer (score 3):

De acordo com a descrição do próprio erro, você possui uma lista de tamanho 25 e está tentando acessar a posição 25.

A lista, porém, possui as posições de 0 a 24. Ou seja, você está tentando acessar um índice que está fora do limite da lista.

Você precisa colocar um breakpoint nesse trecho:

```
if((userSelectionsList.get(i)-1)==correctAnswersList.get(i)){
```

Então você deve inspecionar o que acontece quando você volta uma pergunta e depois avança. 
Provavelmente o que está acontecendo é o seguinte:

1. Você tem um contador de respostas corretas
2. Você está fazendo um loop para saber quantas perguntas o usuário acertou.
3. O loop está programado para repetir 25 vezes.
4. Quando você volta uma pergunta, você deveria decrementar a quantidade de perguntas feitas e decrementar a quantidade de respostas corretas. Porque nessa situação o usuário está respondendo uma pergunta já respondida.

No entanto, parece que ao voltar uma pergunta e respondê-la novamente, o contador continua crescendo. Quando você entra no loop, a quantidade de perguntas respondidas excede os 25.

Ao inspecionar o código você precisa verificar as seguintes informações:

1. O size das listas userSelectionsList e correctAnswersList. Dessa forma você vai saber em qual das duas listas está dando o erro.
2. O valor da variável taken. Essa variável precisa ter o mesmo valor da quantidade de perguntas feitas. Nesse caso, acredito que você não precise disso:
   taken-1. Acredito que você fez isso para evitar o erro.
3. Veja também como essas duas listas estão sendo preenchidas. Lembre-se, o tamanho da lista correctAnswersList deve ser no máximo a quantidade de perguntas feitas.

Espero ter ajudado.
Caso não consiga resolver, post aqui as informações citadas nessa resposta.